# Issues getting custom theme to work with custom action bar

Tags: android

I've been trying to get a custom theme and action bar to work together.  I generated the resources for them with the often-linked sites.  Both work when set up independently in the manifest (only the app theme, or only the action bar), but when used together only the one explicitly stated in the manifest works.

My manifest:

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyActionBar" >
```

MyActionBar's xml file:

```
<style name="Theme.MyActionBar" parent="@style/MyAppTheme">
```

MyAppTheme's xml:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
```

As mentioned above the action bar's style works, but the rest of the theme is AppCompat default.  When I reverse their order, so that MyAppTheme is MyActionBar's child, and the latter is a child of Theme.AppCompat, the application theme works, but the action bar doesn't.

Have I missed something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your ActionBar style into your parent Theme, in `styles.xml`, as follows:

Set your actionBarStyle attribute into your Custom Theme:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/mActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/mActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Then, declare this item above with the ActionBar parent's Widget Theme:

```
<style name="mActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <!-- set your ActionBar theme -->
</style>
```

You can see [Styling the ActionBar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html), it might be very useful with more examples.
Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm away from my main machine at the moment, but I'll try this and accept your answer asap.

Answer (score 0):

This site can generate the styles.xml and all the appropriate resources for you. You can also choose whether to generate stylers that are compliant with pure Android, ActionBarSherlock, or AppCompat.

[ActionBar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=E4E4E4,100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6,100&tabColor=33B5E5,100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2,100&accentColor=33B5E5,100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF,100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5,100)

Comment: Thanks, but I've used that site and holo colors to generate the appropriate files. I also looked into guides for installing both, followed them, and am still having the issue.